# square roots in an exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there any techniques for getting a square root out of an exponential without picking up a square of Ln?

Example: Circular waves in Cartesian coordinates.

Using taylor expansion of e, the even terms lose the root but the odd terms don't. (Am I missing something?)

Ditching the exponential by taking the log of both sides results in the square of a $\ln$.

$$e^{i(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}} = f(x,y)$$

$$i(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} = \ln(f)$$

$$-(x^2 + y^2) = (\ln (f))^2$$

I'm looking for strategies and methods, or mistakes in my above reasoning.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear in your questions. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Solving for a specific variable, or simply trying to rewrite the equation? Also what are you taking the taylor expansion of?

Comment: I'm trying to understand circular waves, but I don't know how to deal with the dependence on distance. Changing coordinates doesn't seem to clarify much.

Comment: @TimCrane Your question and goal are still unclear.  Could you expand on what "deal with the dependence on distance" means?

Comment: I don't know how to deal with this square root. The main example I have is from a circular wave, where the phase of the wave depends on its distance from the center point. However, when I try to solve manipulate this problem into a more intuitive form (any more intuitive form) I can't get around this square-root in the exponential.

Are there any intuitive forms of this problem that get around this square root issue? Also, I would like to know if there is a general strategy for dealing with square-roots in exponentials.

Comment: You keep using that phrase "deal with" but it isn't any clearer what you want to do.  There's no way to simplify $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you Antonio. If you have a reference to that result, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such reference `:)`